# dropdown not showing all item after clone

Tags: jquery, html, .net-core, selectlistitem

I want to cloned and its worked.But dropdownlist not able to select.
I don't know what mistakes that I have done.Hope can help me solve this problem.Thank you.

[image: not able to select drop down]

**DISPLAY TABLE**

```
<table class="table" id="ItemList" style="width:100%">
   <tr>
     <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Field</th>
     <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Cage</th>
     <th class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Tare Weight</th>
     <th class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Gross Weight</th>
     <th class="col-md-2"></th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**CLONE TABLE**

```
<table class="table hide" id="ItemListClone" style="width:100%" >
   <tr>
     <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Field</th>
     <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Cage</th>
     <th class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Tare Weight</th>
     <th class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Gross Weight</th>
     <th class="col-md-2"></th>
   </tr>
   <!-- This is  clonable row line -->
   <tr class="item-cage-clone">
       <td>
         <select class="form-control select " name="FieldID" asp-items="@ViewBag.FieldList">
          <option value="">Choose..</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td>
        <select class="form-control select " name="CageID" asp-items="@ViewBag.CageList">
          <option value="">Choose..</option>
        </select>
       </td>
       <td>
         <label for="WeightContainer" name="WeightContainer"></label>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="number" name="WeightIn" class="form-control">
       </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove cage-remove"></span>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

**ADD CAGE TO TABLE**

```
$('.cage-add').on('click', function (e) {

    var item = $("#ItemListClone").find(".item-cage-clone").clone(true);

    $("#ItemList").append(item);
})
```

Comment: are you not able to click the select box or not seeing options other than 'choose..'?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar  when I select dropdown nothing happen sir.

Comment: looks like when you clone whole row, select box get cloned with no options to select from. You need to copy it explicitly after cloning. Inspect the browser and check. I can help you if you can re create this problem on jsfiddle or code snippet